# R: probable reason 'No such file or directory'

Tags: r, installation, download, package

I am trying to install the following package in R: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MVN/index.html

However, when I try to install this library, I come across the following error:

```
 install.packages("MVN")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/me/Documents/R/win-library/4.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
also installing the dependencies ‘ash’, ‘multicool’, ‘hdrcde’, ‘ks’, ‘rainbow’, ‘fds’, ‘pcaPP’, ‘NADA’, ‘pls’, ‘cvTools’, ‘fda’, ‘rrcov’, ‘sROC’, ‘zCompositions’, ‘sgeostat’, ‘robCompositions’, ‘nortest’, ‘mvoutlier’, ‘energy’, ‘kableExtra’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.0/ash_1.0-15.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 41565 bytes (40 KB)
downloaded 40 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.0/multicool_0.1-11.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 826191 bytes (806 KB)
downloaded 806 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.0/hdrcde_3.3.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 218222 bytes (213 KB)
downloaded 213 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.0/ks_1.11.7.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 1659212 bytes (1.6 MB)
downloaded 1.6 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.0/rainbow_3.6.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 709585 bytes (692 KB)
downloaded 692 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.0/fds_1.8.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 4037417 bytes (3.9 MB)
downloaded 3.9 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.0/pcaPP_1.9-73.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 529201 bytes (516 KB)
downloaded 516 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.0/NADA_1.6-1.1.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 482142 bytes (470 KB)
downloaded 470 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.0/pls_2.7-3.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 1267242 bytes (1.2 MB)
downloaded 1.2 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.0/cvTools_0.3.2.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 217529 bytes (212 KB)
downloaded 212 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.0/fda_5.1.9.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 2372563 bytes (2.3 MB)
downloaded 2.3 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.0/rrcov_1.5-5.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 1847523 bytes (1.8 MB)
downloaded 1.8 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.0/sROC_0.1-2.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 97073 bytes (94 KB)
downloaded 94 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.0/zCompositions_1.3.4.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 233047 bytes (227 KB)
downloaded 227 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.0/sgeostat_1.0-27.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 155679 bytes (152 KB)
downloaded 152 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.0/robCompositions_2.3.0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 3515967 bytes (3.4 MB)
downloaded 3.4 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.0/nortest_1.0-4.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 38707 bytes (37 KB)
downloaded 37 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.0/mvoutlier_2.0.9.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 803299 bytes (784 KB)
downloaded 784 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.0/energy_1.7-7.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 1017695 bytes (993 KB)
downloaded 993 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.0/kableExtra_1.3.1.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 1857883 bytes (1.8 MB)
downloaded 1.8 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.0/MVN_5.8.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 391747 bytes (382 KB)
downloaded 382 KB

package ‘ash’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘multicool’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘hdrcde’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘ks’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘rainbow’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘fds’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘pcaPP’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘NADA’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘pls’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘cvTools’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘fda’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘rrcov’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘sROC’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘zCompositions’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘sgeostat’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘robCompositions’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘nortest’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Warning in install.packages :
  write error in extracting from zip file
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open compressed file 'mvoutlier/DESCRIPTION', probable reason 'No such file or directory'
Error in install.packages : cannot open the connection
```

Is there something wrong with this library? Or is there a problem with my computer? I tried using the github version of this library, but this also resulted in an error as well.

Thanks

Note:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 18363)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_Canada.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_Canada.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_Canada.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                    LC_TIME=English_Canada.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats4    grid      stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] partykit_1.2-10   libcoin_1.0-6     party_1.3-5       strucchange_1.5-2 sandwich_3.0-0    zoo_1.8-8        
 [7] modeltools_0.2-23 mvtnorm_1.1-1     rpart_4.1-15      gridExtra_2.3     ggpubr_0.4.0      patchwork_1.1.1  
[13] ggplot2_3.3.2     dplyr_1.0.2      

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] nlme_3.1-149         fs_1.4.2             matrixStats_0.56.0   usethis_1.6.3        lubridate_1.7.9     
 [6] devtools_2.3.2       rprojroot_1.3-2      tools_4.0.2          backports_1.1.7      R6_2.4.1            
[11] colorspace_1.4-1     nnet_7.3-14          withr_2.3.0          prettyunits_1.1.1    processx_3.4.4      
[16] tidyselect_1.1.0     curl_4.3             compiler_4.0.2       cli_2.1.0            desc_1.2.0          
[21] labeling_0.3         scales_1.1.1         callr_3.5.1          stringr_1.4.0        digest_0.6.25       
[26] foreign_0.8-80       rio_0.5.16           pkgconfig_2.0.3      sessioninfo_1.1.1    rlang_0.4.7         
[31] readxl_1.3.1         rstudioapi_0.11      farver_2.0.3         generics_0.0.2       ModelMetrics_1.2.2.2
[36] zip_2.1.1            car_3.0-10           magrittr_1.5         Formula_1.2-4        Matrix_1.2-18       
[41] Rcpp_1.0.5           munsell_0.5.0        fansi_0.4.1          abind_1.4-5          lifecycle_0.2.0     
[46] stringi_1.4.6        multcomp_1.4-14      pROC_1.16.2          inum_1.0-1           carData_3.0-4       
[51] MASS_7.3-53          pkgbuild_1.1.0       plyr_1.8.6           recipes_0.1.13       parallel_4.0.2      
[56] forcats_0.5.0        crayon_1.3.4         lattice_0.20-41      haven_2.3.1          cowplot_1.1.0       
[61] splines_4.0.2        hms_0.5.3            ps_1.3.3             pillar_1.4.6         ggsignif_0.6.0      
[66] xgboost_1.1.1.1      pkgload_1.1.0        reshape2_1.4.4       codetools_0.2-16     glue_1.4.1          
[71] remotes_2.2.0        data.table_1.12.8    vctrs_0.3.2          foreach_1.5.1        testthat_2.3.2      
[76] cellranger_1.1.0     gtable_0.3.0         purrr_0.3.4          tidyr_1.1.0          assertthat_0.2.1    
[81] xfun_0.15            gower_0.2.2          openxlsx_4.2.2       coin_1.3-1           prodlim_2019.11.13  
[86] broom_0.7.1          rstatix_0.6.0        class_7.3-17         survival_3.2-7       timeDate_3043.102   
[91] tibble_3.0.3         iterators_1.0.13     memoise_1.1.0        tinytex_0.26         lava_1.6.8          
[96] TH.data_1.0-10       ellipsis_0.3.1       caret_6.0-86         ipred_0.9-9
```

Comment: just the "MVN" package

Comment: Try `install.packages("mvoutlier")` and see whether it throws an error

Comment: Might also be worth installing [Rtools40](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/)

Comment: Thank you, I wi try this. If you have time, can you please take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65679523/r-obtaining-rules-from-a-function ? I have been working on this for a while. Thank you

Comment: I had a look at it - it's not really my area of expertise but hopefully my answer is useful